# Cannot delete a document in SharePoint Library which is not checked out neither opened for editing?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepointdocumentlibrary, sharepoint-documents

I am trying to delete a file in SharePoint 2013 Library.
The file is not checked out to anyone and I am the site collection administrator of the site.
when I open the folder using explorer view, it is blank.

When I open it using SharePoint designer then it says

**SERVER ERROR: CANNOT REMOVE THE FILE. ERROR CODE:2.**

Answer (score 0):

Could you delete the file through the SharePoint document library UI?

Whether the file has unique permission? How many characters does the name of this file have?

Please check whether the file is published and approved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new file on your computer with the same file name and extension and then upload it to the same document library then delete it.